# MVC <form action=@Href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwmUFTWEh6Y and i'm having a problem understanding why `@Href`doesn't work.

`@Href` i'm asiming it should be pointing to the `Update ActionResult` in the `PostsController`, but it doesn't work, and i don't see any problem. I have a PostsController as u can see in the picture, and i clearly have a `public ActionResult Update` in the `PostsController`. 
Why does it say `path not found`?

I will probably have no hair left by the end of the tutorial!

[image: <form action="@Href]

**EDIT:**
In the picture i underlined 2 things, but i kinda figured out the other one.

**UPDATE:**

> ```
>    public class PostsController : Controller
> {   
>
> //UPDATE takes (id, title, body, datetime, tags)
> public ActionResult Update(int? id, string title, string body, DateTime dateTime, string tags)
> { .......
> }
> ```

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the controller code. Can you show that?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it in a sec, but i don't think it will help.

Comment: It seems you have a controller `Posts` - assuming you have an action `Update`, it could just be intellisense not grokking the route correctly. You can also use `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` to build the URL, instead of `@Href("~/Controller/Action")`

Comment: @StuartLC I was thinking to do that but is it the same thing as @Href?

Comment: Yes, although it is slightly more encapsulated IMO. Better yet, is [T4 MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) which gives compile time safety, e.g. `@Url.Action(MyProject.Controllers.Action())`. @Tyler - just try build and run the project and see if there are errors - it might just be silliness.

Comment: You're right! It is sillyness. I had another error not letting me build, but after i fixed that it builds even if intellisense it gives me sillyness. Puff ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Url.Action("Update", "Posts")`, it's much more easy to use. Look up the full list of overloaded methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and pick the one that fits your needs.

As an alternative for forms, you could use `@Html.BeginForm()`. Example of usage from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
```

Comment: I wil use `@Url.Action("Update", "Posts")` And also `@Html.BeginForm()` instead of `<form>` is even more interesting. Thanks.

Comment: A key reason for using @Url.Action is because it will reference your route table and automatically match any customised patterns